# Share a local folder over LAN with CIFS

Tags: networking, mount, fstab, file-sharing, cifs

I have a folder (/share, which contains other subfolders and files) which I want it to be shared over my LAN. I've read out there that CIFS (replacing Samba) is the file system adequate to do such a task.

So, what I do is the following:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest.rw //192.168.1.1/shared_folder /share
```

(do not pay attention to the options)

After executing the command, the following messages are shown:

> Retrying with upper case share name
>
> mount error(6): No such device or address
>
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

I've read the man pages and I don't get what the problem is... What am I doing wrong? Perhaps am I not specifying the correct addresses?

After that, I will setup my fstab, but that is not a problem.

Thanks for your dedication.

Comment: have you enabled sharing with nautilus  ? or by /etc/samba/smb.conf ?

Comment: No, I haven't do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On the server (sharing) side** : right click on folder you want to share (e.g Documents) then click properties :

[image]

Enable sharing option (nautilus will download and install samba for you). You may also need to check access for guests.

**On the client side :**

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

and mount it (as guest) :

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //sharing_machine_ip/Documents /mountpoint
```

you can also add some other options like user and password:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=your_username,password=your_password //sharing_machine_ip/Documents /mountpoint
```

If you want this to automount (as guest - indicates you don't need a password to access the share) at startup you can add to the end of **/etc/fstab**:

```
//sharing_machine_ip/Documents  /your_mountpoint  cifs  guest   0 0
```

or with password protected share:

```
//sharing_machine_ip/Documents  /your_mountpoint  cifs  username=your_username,password=your_password   0 0
```