# CIFS share client export share directory to a private local lan?

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba, cifs

Operating Systems: Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04

Package: cifs-utils

System overview: Ubuntu machine acting as a server and a gateway between a public and private LAN for a data acquisition and control environment. The server controls other Ubuntu/Debian machines within the private lan. Machines in the private lan can only communicate with each other and the Ubuntu server/gateway. The server mounts a CIFS share from a Windows 2008 server machine located in the public LAN; this is where "data" is saved.

Problem: I've come across a situation where an Ubuntu machine in the private LAN needs direct RW access to this CIFS share, but due to security reasons it cannot directly mount the share from the public LAN. Also, it is not trivial to remove the private machine to update it with the cifs-utils package.

Thoughts: I originally thought I could just export the CIFS share via NFS to the private machine, but that requires a different software package and is not recommended to overlap the two different file systems.

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to physically remove the private machine and install cifs-utils. This also included having to install the samba package on the server machine. Much like this post:

[Share a local folder over LAN with CIFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732749/share-a-local-folder-over-lan-with-cifs?rq=1)